# In react-redux, store everything (images, profile info, user info, etc) in redux-persist store?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, local-storage, redux-persist

I'm just starting with redux. And I was thinking, instead of using multiple storage systems (localstorage, firebase, redux store, etc..) to just download this tool I read called "Redux-persist" (so the redux store persist even if window is closed), and then store everything there. I know it uses local-storage that is limited to 10mb, but honest, why would I need more? Only 2-3 images and a few thousand words of text max per user is enough for me.

I was thinking this way it'll also all be save in user side all the time, so less downloads and thus less server strain and faster user experience. No?

I'm really new to this so I wanted to ask whether you see any flaw with this plan?

Comment: It depends on your application and use case. Since you know it uses local-storage (or other client-side storage), then see if it suits your app's requirements in terms of storage, security, speed and ease-of-use. No one knows better your app and its requirements.

Comment: This is what databases are for.

Comment: but then, I would like all the data that is saved on client side as coockies in the browser to be stores in a single place. Databases are for my serverside no?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, this seems like a very, very bad idea.

I would visit [this site](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/) to check the limits of `localStorage` - they aren't as consistent as you may think.

Also, `localStorage` would limit that 'store' to that browser, on that machine.

What type of content are you expecting to download? It's difficult to offer an alternative without knowing more about the scenario you are working with.

Comment: So far it's just a simple website with users with a profile page. Later I would add ability to set up meetings (calendar) and video chat. I think that's mostly it.
btw "Also, localStorage would limit that 'store' to that browser, on that machine." aren't all cookies like that?

Comment: Depends what you mean when you say `store everything there`. You shouldn't rely on the client storage for your user data for obvious reasons so you'll need to decide how you reconcile between the client storage and your server storage. If you're simply looking to improve performance through caching you're almost certainly better off setting your media cache headers appropriately so the browser can handle caching images vs trying to do that yourself in local storage.

Comment: This is true, but cookies are designed to hold *small* amounts of information, they can also expire and be removed from the session. What you are talking about is potentially storing a users profile in local storage. If I use a shared machine and do not log out properly, now my profile data is available for the next person that uses that machine. It's your choice, but it's not an approach I would ever take with PII data.

Comment: I would honestly suggest plugging in something like `firebase` if you are looking for a simple solution. It will help your app scale in the future and provide a much better experience for you as a dev and your user as a consumer.

Comment: So far I'm using express+mongodb for my backend needs. Considering my description, would you say it is recommended to migrate to firebase? also, where would you save the user token if not in localstorate, should I save it in the redux store (but then it's lost on user refresh)?